# Pytorch doesn't support one-hot vector?

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch

I am very confused by how Pytorch deals with one-hot vectors. In this [tutorial](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/blitz/cifar10_tutorial.html), the neural network will generate a one-hot vector as its output. As far as I understand, the schematic structure of the neural network in the tutorial should be like:

[image]

However, the `labels` are not in one-hot vector format. I get the following `size`

```
print(labels.size())
print(outputs.size())

output>>> torch.Size([4]) 
output>>> torch.Size([4, 10])
```

Miraculously, I they pass the `outputs` and `labels` to `criterion=CrossEntropyLoss()`, there's no error at all.

```
loss = criterion(outputs, labels) # How come it has no error?
```

### My hypothesis:

Maybe pytorch automatically convert the `labels` to one-hot vector form. So, I try to convert labels to one-hot vector before passing it to the loss function.

```
def to_one_hot_vector(num_class, label):
    b = np.zeros((label.shape[0], num_class))
    b[np.arange(label.shape[0]), label] = 1

    return b

labels_one_hot = to_one_hot_vector(10,labels)
labels_one_hot = torch.Tensor(labels_one_hot)
labels_one_hot = labels_one_hot.type(torch.LongTensor)

loss = criterion(outputs, labels_one_hot) # Now it gives me error
```

However, I got the following error

> RuntimeError: multi-target not supported at
>   /opt/pytorch/pytorch/aten/src/THCUNN/generic/ClassNLLCriterion.cu:15

So, one-hot vectors are not supported in `Pytorch`? How does `Pytorch` calculates the `cross entropy` for the two tensor `outputs = [1,0,0],[0,0,1]` and `labels = [0,2]` ? It doesn't make sense to me at all at the moment.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

PyTorch states in its documentation for [`CrossEntropyLoss`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss) that

> This criterion expects a class index (0 to C-1) as the target for each value of a 1D tensor of size minibatch

In other words, it has your `to_one_hot_vector` function conceptually built in `CEL` and does not expose the one-hot API. Notice that one-hot vectors are memory inefficient compared to storing class labels.

If you are given one-hot vectors and need to go to class labels format (for instance  to be compatible with `CEL`), you can use `argmax` like below:

```
import torch
 
labels = torch.tensor([1, 2, 3, 5])
one_hot = torch.zeros(4, 6)
one_hot[torch.arange(4), labels] = 1
 
reverted = torch.argmax(one_hot, dim=1)
assert (labels == reverted).all().item()
```

Comment: **So there's no need to one hot encode classes when using nn.CrossEntropyLoss**


Note that "The combination of nn.LogSoftmax and nn.NLLLoss is equivalent to using
nn.CrossEntropyLoss.", so if your sequential you have a nn.LogSoftmax, and the you have a loss = nn.NLLLoss, you don't need to one hot encode either.

Answer (score 15):

This code will help you with both *one hot encode* and *multi hot encode*:

```
import torch
batch_size=10
n_classes=5
target = torch.randint(high=5, size=(1,10)) # set size (2,10) for MHE
print(target)
y = torch.zeros(batch_size, n_classes)
y[range(y.shape[0]), target]=1
y
```

The output in OHE

```
tensor([[4, 3, 2, 2, 4, 1, 1, 1, 4, 2]])

tensor([[0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
        [0., 0., 0., 1., 0.],
        [0., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
        [0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
        [0., 0., 1., 0., 0.]])
```

The output for MHE when I set `target = torch.randint(high=5, size=(2,10))`

```
tensor([[3, 2, 4, 4, 2, 4, 0, 4, 4, 1],
        [4, 1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 4, 2, 4, 3]])

tensor([[0., 0., 0., 1., 1.],
        [0., 1., 1., 0., 0.],
        [0., 1., 0., 0., 1.],
        [0., 0., 0., 1., 1.],
        [0., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 1., 0., 1.],
        [1., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
        [0., 0., 1., 0., 1.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
        [0., 1., 0., 1., 0.]])
```

If you need multiple OHE:

```
torch.nn.functional.one_hot(target)

tensor([[[0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
         [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
         [0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
         [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
         [1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
         [0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
         [0, 1, 0, 0, 0]],

        [[0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
         [0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
         [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
         [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
         [0, 0, 0, 1, 0]]])
```

Comment: Here is a specific use case on hoe to use the one_hot in a transform, because that is what we are all looking for:
```
target_transform=torchvision.transforms.Compose([
                                 lambda x:torch.LongTensor([x]),
                                 lambda x:F.one_hot(x,10)],
                                 lambda x: x.squeeze()])
```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63342147/how-to-transform-labels-in-pytorch-to-onehot

Answer (score 1):

As stated clearly by @Jatentaki, you can use `torch.argmax(one_hot, dim=1)` to convert the one-hot encoded vectors to numbers.

However, if you still want to train your network with one-hot encoded output in PyTorch, you can use [`nn.LogSoftmax`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.LogSoftmax.html#logsoftmax) along with [`NLLLOSS`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.NLLLoss.html#nllloss):

```py
import torch
from torch import nn

output_onehot = nn.LogSoftmax(dim=1)(torch.randn(3, 5)) # m = 3 samples, each has n = 5 features
target = torch.tensor([1, 0, 4]) # target values for each sample

nn.NLLLoss()(output_onehot, target)

print(output_onehot)
print(target)

# You can get the probabilities using the exponential function:
print("Probabilities:", torch.exp(output_onehot))
```

The output will be something like this:

```sh
tensor([[-0.5413, -2.4461, -2.0110, -1.9964, -2.7851],
        [-2.3376, -1.6985, -1.8472, -3.0975, -0.6585],
        [-3.2820, -0.7160, -1.5297, -1.5636, -3.0412]])
tensor([1, 0, 4])
Probabilities: tensor([[0.5820, 0.0866, 0.1339, 0.1358, 0.0617],
        [0.0966, 0.1830, 0.1577, 0.0452, 0.5176],
        [0.0376, 0.4887, 0.2166, 0.2094, 0.0478]])
```

Answer (score 0):

The original post was for a few years ago, the documentation for [CrossEntropyLoss](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss.html#torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss) may have changed since then. According to that, targets can be either in the form of probabilities for each class (here one-hot encoded) or class indices.

You can convert a numpy array labels from class type to one-hot encoded vectors:

```
import torch.nn.functional as F
class_labels = torch.Tensor(numpy_class_labels)
one_hot_labels = F.one_hot(class_labels, num_classes=n_classes)
labels = labels.type(torch.DoubleTensor)
loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
```

Or you can do the reverse and convert the one-hot encoded labels to classes:

```
one_hot_labels = torch.Tensor(numpy_one_hot_labels)
_, class_labels = torch.max(one_hot_labels, 1)
labels = class_labels.type(torch.LongTensor)
loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
```

Just be cautious about the Long and Double formats above, and note that using classes is preferable as the documentation says:

> The performance of this criterion is generally better when target contains class indices, as this allows for optimized computation. Consider providing target as class probabilities only when a single class label per minibatch item is too restrictive.