# How to transform labels in pytorch to onehot

Tags: pytorch, torch, mnist, one-hot-encoding, torchvision

How to give `target_transform` a function for changing the labels to **onehot** encoding?

For example, the MNIST dataset in torchvision:

```
train_dataset = torchvision.datasets.MNIST(root='./mnist_data/', 
                                           train=True,
                                           download=True,
                                           transform=train_transform,
                                           target_transform=<????>)
```

Tried `F.onehot()` but it didn't work.

Comment: whats the issue with F.onehot() ? its working fine for me as `torch.nn.functional.one_hot(torch.tensor(2),5).type(torch.cuda.FloatTensor)`

Answer (score 2):

This is how I implemented it. Not sure if there's a cleaner way.

```py
train_dataset = torchvision.datasets.MNIST(root='./data/', train=True,
                                 transform=torchvision.transforms.ToTensor(),
                                 target_transform=torchvision.transforms.Compose([
                                 lambda x:torch.LongTensor([x]), # or just torch.tensor
                                 lambda x:F.one_hot(x,10)]),
                                 download=True)
```

- It needs to be an `index tensor`? i.e. int64
- Can't use `torchvision.ToTensor` because it's not an image
- Also `torch.LongTensor` and `torch.tensor` behave differently with `int` input
- Need to provide number of classes

Answer (score 1):

Use **lambda** user-defined function to turn the integer into a one-hot encoded tensor.

```py
train_dataset = torchvision.datasets.MNIST(root='./mnist_data/', train=True, 
    download=True, transform=train_transform, 
    target_transform=Lambda(lambda y: torch.zeros(10, dtype=torch.float).scatter_(0, torch.tensor(y), value=1))
```

- It first creates a zero tensor of size 10 (the number of labels in our dataset)
  and calls scatter_ which assigns a value=1 on the index as given by the label y.