# PyTorch input/output data sizes

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch

I'm trying out PyTorch for the first time, and running into a couple problems. I've shared some of my code below and have two questions.

Q1: What should my output size be? Each input should lead to one output, equal to one of 6 possible output labels (1-6). Should output size be 1 or 6?

Q2: Something is wrong with my accuracy calculation, which I think is tied into Q1. `predicted` ends up being of size `4 x 4411`, where 4 is my batch size (and so I think that's correct) but 4411 is my feature/input size, which is almost certainly wrong. I would expect it to be 6 (number of possible output labels). `labels` is 4x6, which I think is correct. If I change the dim I'm taking the max over from 1 to 2, then it gets the correct size of 4x6, but logically it makes no sense as it's returning the max index across all feature values for an input.

I think I'm missing something crucial about what pytorch is doing with my data. I feel so close.... Any ideas on how I can fix this? Thanks!

````
    def __init__(self, input_size, output_size, hidden_dim, n_layers):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.input_size  = input_size
        self.output_size = output_size
        self.hidden_dim  = hidden_dim
        self.n_layers    = n_layers

        self.rnn = torch.nn.RNN(input_size, hidden_dim, n_layers, batch_first=True)
        # Q1: What should my output_size be?
        self.fc = torch.nn.Linear(hidden_dim, output_size)

    def forward(self, x):
        batch_size = x.size(0)
        hidden = self.init_hidden(batch_size)
        out, hidden = self.rnn(x, hidden)
        out = self.fc(out)
        return out, hidden

    def init_hidden(self, batch_size):
        return torch.zeros(self.n_layers, batch_size, self.hidden_dim)
if __name__ == '__main__':
   # ... code removed that just creates the Dataloaders, and initialises some size variables

    net = Net(input_size=dataset.input_size, output_size=6, hidden_dim=24, n_layers=1)
    net.to(device)
    criterion = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
    optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(net.parameters(), lr=lr)

    for epoch in range(1, epochs+1):
        total = 0
        correct = 0
        for inputs, labels in dataloaders['train']:
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            inputs, labels = inputs.to(device), labels.to(device)
            output, hidden = net(inputs)
            loss = criterion(output, labels) # error
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()

            # Q2: Something is wrong here
            _, predicted = torch.max(output.data, 1)
            total += inputs.size(0)
            correct += (predicted == labels).sum().item()
            print(predicted == labels)
        accuracy = 100 * correct / total```
````

Answer (score 1):

1. Pytorch's [`CrossEntropyLoss`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55549843/pytorch-doesnt-support-one-hot-vector) expects `output` of size `(n)` (with the score of each of the n classes) and `label` as an integer of the correct class's index.
2. Your rnn based model is spitting out tensors of shape `[batch, input_size, 6]`, since it is an rnn and producing a sequence of the same length as the input (with 6 scores per element of the sequence). If you wish to have one class label prediction per sequence (not per element of sequence) you will need to collapse this to a tensor of shape `[batch, 6]`.

Comment: How do I collapse the output to `[batch, 6]`? I think that's what I need to do, but I don't know how to reduce those `input_size` values into one (per input).

Comment: I wasn't sure about the correct structure of `label`, so thanks for correcting me! I fixed that.

Comment: @moinudin you could create 6 'sister' linear layers taking as input the `input_size` values per label and outputing one value, and then concatenate their outputs.

Comment: I think I understand, except I'm not sure how you'd concatenate their outputs? I'm giving it a try now.

Comment: @moinudin `torch.cat`

Comment: Is this the right idea? https://gist.github.com/marcogallotta/fd8679e2cdd66def44b78e6decf11b8b (putting it after running the rnn.)